# Problemas con: <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar

Tags: android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy aprendiendo a usar Android Studio y cada vez que creo un bottom app bar en la visualizzación(desing), simplemente me aparece: com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar . No se si es un problema de dependencias o en themes.xml()

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar">
</com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>




dependencies {
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
}
```

Quiero solucionar mi problema de visualización, no me esta permitiendo elaborar el Bottom App Bar

Comment: Hola. ¿Cuál es el mensaje de error exactamente?